# Rest API parameters are empty Serializer without model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my view, I am not able to retrieve parameter coming in the rest API. when i print data i get {'in_text': ''}

serializers.py

```
class StandardizerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    in_text = serializers.CharField(max_length=2000,required=False)
```

views.py

```
class standardiz_text(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        #serializer =  StandardizerSerializer(context={'request': request})
        serializer =  StandardizerSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(repr(serializer))
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            print(serializer.data)
        else:
            print("----------not valid")
        return Response({'standardizer_text': ' test data'})
```

url to call from postman

http://127.0.0.1:8000/standardiz/text/?in_text=tesinput

outpt is

```
StandardizerSerializer(data={}):
    in_text = CharField(max_length=2000, required=False)
{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the **`in_text`** data as ***url query parameter***. URL query parameters are located inside the [**`request.query_params`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) attribute. So, if you want to serialize something from `query_params`, you have to pass it to the serializer instead of **`request.data`**

```
#code
class standardiz_text(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = StandardizerSerializer(data=request.query_params) # change is here <<<<<
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            print(serializer.data)
        else:
            print("----------not valid")
        return Response({'standardizer_text': ' test data'})
```